# Issue with receiving push notifications on iOS using Capacitor and Firebase

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am facing a problem with receiving push notifications on iOS using Capacitor and Firebase Cloud Messaging. Here are the details:

- I'm using @capacitor/push-notifications, and followed the setup steps provided in the [plugin documentation for iOS](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications#ios).
- Android devices receive notifications successfully, but iOS devices do not.
- `PushNotifications.register()` runs successfully and the FCM token is obtained from iOS device.
- Notification permission is asked at first startup. I also checked the app settings. Notifications are enabled.
- I have downloaded GoogleService-Info.plist from FCM and pasted it into the root of my IOS project.
- I have uploaded the APNs Certificates for both Development and Production modes in FCM dashboard.
- Im using  `"@capacitor/core": "^5.0.0"`, `"@capacitor/push-notifications": "^5.0.4"` and `"@capacitor/ios": "^5.0.5"`.
- I have tried sending a test notification directly to that device from FCM dashboard (using device FCM token), but no notification is received.
- I have tried this scenario on a real device and an emulator. still no luck.

Despite these steps, notifications are not received on iOS devices/emulators. I would appreciate any guidance.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this guide helps you: https://capawesome.io/blog/the-push-notifications-guide-for-capacitor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [@capacitor-firebase/messaging](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase) plugin instead of `@capacitor/push-notifications` and that worked for me.

( [This guide](https://capawesome.io/blog/the-push-notifications-guide-for-capacitor) helped me ,Thanks to [RGe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6731412/rge) )

Comment: This fixed the problem for me! The main difference I've noticed is now the registration token generated on iOS is similar to Android whereas before it was looking to something like `3B7CA1BCAE6B0C972CCE9D9D10B98E88160185A8D65C08294F4EFBA509D5E539`